# Marklogic Smart Mastering option for custom noextract match when extact match fails

Tags: marklogic

We have a requirement where we have to perform the match on the EIN of the party. If exact EIN match does not find any party, we will be matching party using the "levenshtein distance" custom algorithm.

With Smart mastering, I don't see match option, for configuring the custom algorithm which should be evaluated only if there is no party with an exact match?

Answer (score 0):

Smart Mastering, for performance reasons, requires the custom algorithms to return cts:queries and a single search is run. Ideally, you'd balance the weight of those queries such that given the correct criteria is met those weights would add up beyond the threshold to trigger a merge.

There are a couple of options that you could attempt, that you would need to decide if they properly meet your needs.

1.) Passed into the "values" entry of the map (or JSON Object if using JavaScript) is the actual node from the document, so fn:root/fn.root (http://docs.marklogic.com/fn.root) could be called on the node to grab the root and then navigate to the EIN value. You could then conditionally add your weighted query based off whether xdmp:estimate or cts.estimate (http://docs.marklogic.com/cts.estimate) give you a count.

2.) You could have two different sets of match and merge options. The first set matches/ merges on EIN, adding a special collection to the documents without matches. The second set runs against the collection of non-matches on the first run and that uses your Levenstein query.

I think that the first option is probably the best route to go.